# iteration on Datasource in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to make a function which iterates through an array of object and set the property status to false.
The array of obj is a datasource on angular table.

```
this.lightService.getLamp()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      this.lampData = response;
      this.dataSource.data = response;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log('error ' + error);
    }
```

The Data source

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "group" : 1,
        "name": "Lamp 1",
        "connected": " Not Connected",
        "status": true,
        "address": "1",
        "channel": "All",
        "temperature": 3200,
        "error": false,
        "errorMessage": "Not Working at this moment"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group" : 2,
        "name": "Lamp 2",
        "connected": "Connected",
        "status": true,
        "address": "2",
        "channel": "All",
        "temperature": 6500,
        "error": false,
        "errorMessage": "Not Working at this moment"
    },
    {
        .....
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What is your problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Show datasource array

Comment: Please post dataSource json object here in the question

Comment: `result = this.dataSource.data.map(x=x.status=false)`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.map` operator for iterating through all the objects in an array. I suppose the below code should work for you.

```
this.lightService.getLamp()
.subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.lampData = response;
    this.dataSource.data = response;
    this.dataSource.data.map(item => {
     item.status = false
     })
  },
 (error) => {
  console.log('error ' + error);
 }
```

Comment: I just have error . error TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: Ok.. did you get this error while building this code for production? If so try `this.dataSource.data.map((item:any) => { item.status = false })`.. although this is generally not advised

Comment: Great ! Thanks !